# Different output every time the DCC-GARCH Fit function: "rmgarch::dccfit" is called

Tags: r, regression, libraries, numeric

When calling *dccfit* using the *rmgarch* library, I observe strange and inconsistent behavior. If you run a DCC Garch fit on a time series, there are cases where the final fit is different for the same input data. I noticed this by running multiple regressions with a fixed time series data set while using an expanding window.

**Example**

For a fixed, monthly time series spanning [1990-12-31, 2023-04-30]: Assume you encounter the issue running a regression spanning [1990-12-31, 2018-10-31]. This means that every time you run the regression, it results in a different fit. However, expanding the window by a single month (2018-11-30 endpoint) results in the same fit every time you run the regression. If you repeat this process of expanding the time series by a single month until 2023-04-30, the issue appears again at most one extra time. But the problem never shows up in two consecutive months.

I reproduced the issue with different time series data sets. It showed up in two specific, non consecutive dates every time. The dates themselves, *for the same fixed time series*, differ between operative systems. This means that porting the data required me to run a regression every month for the same time series until you found the two different date endpoints where the issue shows up for that particular OS.

[Here you can download a short script and an RDS file needed to reproduce the problem](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-hSn-pV-hfZRYaCFfuyMVV3Of4qA-8hl?usp=sharing). The RDS file includes a monthly time series with a date range spanning [1996-12-31, 2023-03-31]. In the script, I include the date endpoints where the issue shows up for some operative systems I tried. Uncomment the line corresponding to your OS and run the script at least twice. You should get a different regression every time. But the regression will be consistent every time for the other endpoints.

My `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8        LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8      
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8       LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dplyr_1.1.0       data.table_1.14.8 rmgarch_1.3-9     rugarch_1.4-9     Quandl_2.11.0     XLConnect_1.0.7   tseries_0.10-53   quantmod_0.4.20   TTR_0.24.3       
[10] xts_0.13.0        zoo_1.8-11        sqldf_0.4-11      RSQLite_2.3.0     gsubfn_0.7        proto_1.0.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] mclust_6.0.0                Rcpp_1.0.10                 mvtnorm_1.1-3               lattice_0.20-45             corpcor_1.6.10             
 [6] digest_0.6.31               utf8_1.2.3                  gmp_0.7-1                   truncnorm_1.0-8             R6_2.5.1                   
[11] chron_2.3-59                Bessel_0.6-0                pcaPP_2.0-3                 pracma_2.4.2                httr_1.4.5                 
[16] pillar_1.8.1                rlang_1.0.6                 curl_5.0.0                  rstudioapi_0.14             blob_1.2.3                 
[21] SkewHyperbolic_0.4-0        Matrix_1.5-3                bit_4.0.5                   compiler_4.2.2              numDeriv_2016.8-1.1        
[26] pkgconfig_2.0.3             DistributionUtils_0.6-0     tcltk_4.2.2                 tidyselect_1.2.0            Rsolnp_1.16                
[31] tibble_3.1.8                ff_4.0.9                    quadprog_1.5-8              fansi_1.0.4                 MASS_7.3-58.2              
[36] GeneralizedHyperbolic_0.8-4 grid_4.2.2                  jsonlite_1.8.4              lifecycle_1.0.3             DBI_1.1.3                  
[41] magrittr_2.0.3              KernSmooth_2.23-20          cli_3.6.0                   cachem_1.0.7                Rmpfr_0.9-1                
[46] vctrs_0.5.2                 generics_0.1.3              spd_2.0-1                   tools_4.2.2                 bit64_4.0.5                
[51] glue_1.6.2                  ks_1.14.0                   fastmap_1.1.1               memoise_2.0.1               rJava_1.0-6
```